# how to pass value to an angular function using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass the value of the `ng-model="alertThreshold.value"` but when I click on `<a  class="spin-up" data-spin="up" ng-click = "getAlertThreshold(alertThreshold.value)"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>` or `<a  class="spin-down" data-spin="down ng-click = "getAlertThreshold(alertThreshold.value)"" ><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>`
it just call the function without updating the value, the value is always = 10.

```
<div class="input-group spinner" data-trigger="spinner">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="0" data-rule="quantity" ng-model="alertThreshold.value" min="0" max="50" ng-change ="getAlertThreshold(alertThreshold.value)">
                          <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <a  class="spin-up" data-spin="up" ng-click = "getAlertThreshold(alertThreshold.value)"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
                            <a  class="spin-down" data-spin="down" ng-click = "getAlertThreshold(alertThreshold.value)"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

and in my controller:

```
$scope.alertThreshold = {
        value: 10
    };

$scope.getAlertThreshold = function(value){
    console.log("value:",value)
    $scope.alertThreshold.value = value;
}
```

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. Doesn't really make sense reassigning in the `ng-change`

Comment: Your code is working exactly as it should.  What exactly are you trying to achieve on the clicks?  @Murat has the correct answer if you are trying to increment your values up and down one.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$scope.alertThreshold.value` is always the same because take the value of the input. It's like `$scope.alertThreshold.value = $scope.alertThreshold.value` every `ng-click` or `ng-change`

Answer (score 0):

ng-click = "getAlertThreshold(++alertThreshold.value)" ng-click = "getAlertThreshold(--alertThreshold.value)" may resolve the issue.